# Bootstrap4.1.x Dropdown in Navbar pills calls tab content only ones

Tags: bootstrap-4

my responsive Navbar with pills and pills content is working nice. As I tried to implement a drowdown inside the navbar I realisiced that it doesn't work, because the pills content links inide that dropdown are only working ones. Also the links stay active while a different tab is called.

So how to implement a drowdown that is looking like a pills and also has the same funcinalaty like a collapsable pills navbar. A collapsable pills navbar inside a collapsable pills navbar?

https://jsfiddle.net/LuckyLuzz/7j2oe0pb/

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-md navbar-light border-bottom">
        <div class="container-fluid   justify-content-center" id="navbarwidth">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <span class="menu-collapsed pl-4 ml-4">LOGO</span>
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center justify-content-center" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <div class="nav nav-pills nav-fill flex-column flex-md-row" id="pills-tab" role="navigation">
                    <a class="nav-link  active " id="pills-status-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#pills-status"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-status" aria-selected="true">
                        <p class="div" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show" aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-controls="collapseThree" href="#">Dashboard
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-led-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#pills-led" role="tab"
                        aria-controls="pills-led" aria-selected="false">
                        <p class="div" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show" aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-controls="collapseThree" href="#">TEST1
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="pillsv-pH-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#pills-pH" role="tab"
                        aria-controls="pills-pH" aria-selected="false">
                        <p class="div" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show" aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-controls="collapseThree" href="#">TEST2
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <!--DROPDOWN----------------------------------------------->
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="tab">Menu 1
                            
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link " id="pills-Dstatus-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#pills-Dstatus"
                                    role="tab" aria-controls="pills-Dstatus" aria-selected="true">
                                    <p class="div" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show"
                                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" href="#">Dashboard
                                    </p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-Dled-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#pills-Dled"
                                    role="tab" aria-controls="pills-Dled" aria-selected="false">
                                    <p class="div" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show"
                                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" href="#">TEST1
                                    </p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                     <!--DROPDOWN----------------------------------------------->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
        <!-- Status------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="pills-status" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-status-tab">
            DASHBOARD
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="pills-led" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-led-tab">
            TEST1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="pills-pH" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-pH-tab">
            TEST2
        </div>
         <div class="tab-pane" id="pills-Dstatus" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-Dstatus-tab">
           Dropdown DASHBOARD
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="pills-Dled" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-Dled-tab">
           Dropdown TEST1
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example I hope this will help you and Please follow the docs of bootstrap 4.1

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
#pills-tab li.nav-item.dropdown.show .nav-link {
  background: transparent;
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}
#pills-tab li.nav-item.dropdown.show .nav-link.active {
  background: #007bff;
}
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 navbar-nav" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-dashboard-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-status" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-status" aria-selected="true">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-test1-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-led" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-led" aria-selected="false">TEST1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-TEST2-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-pH" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-pH" aria-selected="false">TEST2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#"  id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu nav-pills" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-dashboardinner-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-Dstatus" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-status" aria-selected="false">Dashboard</a>
        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-test1inner-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-Dled" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-led" aria-selected="false">TEST1</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <!-- Status------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="pills-status" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-status-tab">
    DASHBOARD
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="pills-led" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-led-tab">
    TEST1
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="pills-pH" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-pH-tab">
    TEST2
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="pills-Dstatus" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-Dstatus-tab">
   Dropdown DASHBOARD
 </div>
 <div class="tab-pane" id="pills-Dled" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-Dled-tab">
   Dropdown TEST1
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi! There is the jsfiddle with navbar collapse on klick.

https://jsfiddle.net/LuckyLuzz/jyo2zrep/